# How to lazy-load `oil.nvim` on `FileExplorer` event?

Tags: neovim, lua, events, plugin-lazy, plugin-oil

I have next `oil.nvim` setup (in `lazy.nvim` of course):

```
return {
    {
        'stevearc/oil.nvim',

        cmd = { "Oil" },
        event = { "FileExplorer" },


        opts = {
            -- Oil will take over directory buffers (e.g. `vim .` or `:e src/`)
            -- Set to false if you still want to use netrw.
            default_file_explorer = true,
         --   ...
        }
     }
}
```

Also, I have keyibnd for `oil.nvim` set:

```
vim.keymap.set("n", "-", "<CMD>Oil<CR>", { desc = "Open parent directory" })
```

The `FileExplorer` event is described in `:h autocmd` as:

```
                        *FileExplorer*
There is one group that is recognized by Vim: FileExplorer.  If this group
exists Vim assumes that editing a directory is possible and will trigger a
plugin that lists the files in that directory.  This is used by the |netrw|
plugin.  This allows you to do:  
    browse edit
```

So, it should meet my requirements, the `oil.nvim` should be loaded when the `:Oil` is triggered, or, when I open nvim as `$ nvim .`, and the `oil.nivm` gets loaded and replaces the `netrw`.

If I try to run this config, I get next errors:

[image]

This is the output from `$ nivm`. When I run `$ nvim .` I get the same errors and the `netrw` file manager open, instead of `oil.nvim`. If I remove the `event`, then `$ nvim .` opens `netrw` because no `:Oil` command has ben triggered. Of course, if I remove the `cmd` and `event` everything works as intended, but I get no lazy loading for `oil.nvim`.

The question is: Why the event `FileExplorer` is invalid? How to lazy load `oil.nvim` so it will work with `$ nvim .`?

Comment: FileExplorer is a group, not event. Directory is just a special file, so there is no event for a directory to open. Only a generic one for a file.

Comment: @Matt Dang. Thank you for explanation. It seems like there is no way to properly lazy-load `oil.nvim`...

Comment: Lazy loading is to be implemented by plugin's author, not by user.

Comment: @Matt Really? Like if I pass `lazy = true` pluginspec, the plugin will know that he is being lazy-loaded and do something about it? Am I getting it right?

Comment: No, a well-designed plugin should keep events/commands/mapping registration separate from the core functionality code base being loaded on demand. Then users will never had any reason to re-implement such stuff themselves.